# ruby httpclient & NTLM

Tags: ruby, httpclient, ntlm

I am trying to do what look simple but clearly isn't - authenticate with NTLM.

The example in the documentation (http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.1.5.2/HTTPClient) looks straightforward, but when I try it I always get a 401.

I created a simple website in IIS whch requires NTLM.  I tested this works in IE & chrome.

I then

```
require 'httpclient'
require 'pp'
require 'kconv'    #seemed to be needed due to a bug..
require 'rubyntlm' # probably not needed directly?  

domain = 'http://qvcluster1/'
url = 'http://qvcluster1/default.htm'
user = 'testuser'
password = 'testpassword'
client = HTTPClient.new
client.set_auth(nil ,user,password)
r = client.get("http://qvcluster1/default.htm")
pp r
```

From my understanding there is not much more to it, yet it is failing

this is the tail end of what I get from the last line:

```
@reason_phrase="Unauthorized",
@request_absolute_uri=nil,
@request_method="GET",
@request_query=nil,
@request_uri=#<URI::HTTP http://qvcluster1/default.htm>,
@status_code=401>,
```

Any suggestions are appreciated !

As an aside, I just tested from curl and this works fine:

```
"C:\Program Files\cURL\bin\curl.exe" --ntlm  -u testuser:testpassword http://qvcluster1/default.htm
```

Comment: NB:  I have gotten the raw example that comes with rubyntlm to work, so it is clearly an issue with my code or HTTPClient

Answer (score 0):

False Alarm - as it turns out there were problems with the web server communicating with the domain controller so it was messing up authentication.  I removed and re-added it to the domain and all is fine now!